# Is there a problem with a media enclosure box in a laundry room?

Tags: data-wiring, laundry

Looked at a home where the media enclosure box is in the laundry room. Is that ok?
Particularly, I’m unsure if there’s an issue about moisture being near wiring.

Comment: If the laundry room is that wet, there's a problem that has nothing to do with the data wiring. If there is hardware (router, switch) the stray lint might be an issue more concerning. If it's just wiring, not a big concern.

Comment: Such moisture would cause larger mold issues than harm to electronics, which typically don't mind humidity, even in excess.

Comment: Does mains power come into this box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard laundry room inside a home is normally classified as a dry location. Sheetrock on the walls? This is a clue it is dry as defined by code.  There can be a washer or a basin directly adjacent to a breaker box. An outlet would need to be GFCI protected.
Other than a clothes closet and a bathroom your panel can go just about anyplace that has a 30” wide space floor to ceiling. Although you are asking about your media box it has less restrictions. Receptacles in a garage now require GFCI protection if you have line powered devices. If the house is older it may not have GFCI protection.